# what is the best solution to solve the Issue in IE8 with HTML5 and Css3

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I' ve website HTML5, Css3 and Jquery, it is look fine in IE9, but not look good in IE8

I read all solutions here, plus using all methods 
Such as

- CSS3 PIE
- ie7-js

-

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="normal.css" type="text/css" />
  <!--[if lt IE 9]><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie8.css"><![endif]-->
  <!--[if lt IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie7.css"><![endif]-->
```

-

```
 <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js">          
  </script><![endif]-->   
  <script>
  document.createElement('header');
  document.createElement('nav');
  document.createElement('hgroup');
  document.createElement('section');
  document.createElement('article');
  document.createElement('aside');
  document.createElement('footer');
  </script>
```

and.... and....

i can't find the best way to appear website fine in IE8

any help Plz.

website: [moic-egypt.com](http://www.moic-egypt.com)

Answer (score 1):

I won't recommend css3pie, it causes several side effects.

For the styling issue with html5 elements, you're correctly using a shim/shiv (like [html5shiv](https://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/)), so you don't need the `document.createElement` part. That will solve most of the issues.

Instead of creating custom CSS stylesheets for IE, i would switch to [conditional comments](http://paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/), so that you can add specific ie rules in the main CSS:

```
.ie #specificdiv { /* custom rule for ie */ }
```

When your project gets bigger you won't have to browse all the different sheets.

Then [ie9.js](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/), that's for css selectors (like `:not`) which weren't supported in older IE versions.

You've css3 properties left. For these, i'm afraid you'll have to search for fallbacks/polyfills one by one. Here are some beutiful resources to start with:

- [html5please](http://html5please.com/)
- [Can I use](http://caniuse.com/)
- [List of cross-browser polyfills](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills)